# how to open a port 5250 on redhat

Tags: wordpress, tcp, redhat, iptables

I have configured a website but it seems not to be accessible and I found that I must open a port of 5250. I searched and I could not find a good way to do it. I am wondering if anyone could advise ?
I was reading that by default it is stored in

vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

which I only see

```
# sample configuration for iptables service
# you can edit this manually or use system-config-firewall
# please do not ask us to add additional ports/services to this default configuration
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8089 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

then I added the following

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5250 -j ACCEPT
```

then I restarted

I also tried to see the firewall status which made me more confused

```
# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

Comment: by default http uses port 80 what happens if you go to http://yourdomain.com:5250 ?

Comment: @Jasper B basically nothing happens

Comment: can you try chaning this rule `-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5250 -j ACCEPT` to `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5250 -j ACCEPT`